# How to upgrade version number for previous release with semantic-release

Tags: github, semantic-versioning

Currently, I have a package with currnet version 2.0.1, i want to release fix for previous version i.e v1.0.1, how to achieve this in github, should i checkout to v1.0.1 branch and then create fix and merge it to master ? Are there any steps which we need to follow ? I know that i cant merge branch from v1 into master since my master is on v2, so not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll make a new branch from the latest v1 release. Your v1 and v2 are going to diverge. v1 and master (v2) will remain separate.

- Checkout v1.0.1
- Make a branch, name it something like v1

Now work on v1 and tag releases as if it were master.

***Do not*** merge v1 into master. ***Do not*** merge master into v1. These are now two active release branches.

If you want bug fixes from v2, use [git-cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#_rebase_cherry_pick) to copy individual commits from master to v1.